# Python: Move files to folder based on Part of File name

Tags: python

Folder contains files

1. filenameone_partone_1
2. filenameone_partone_2
3. filenameone_partone_3
4. filenameone_parttwo_1
5. filenameone_parttwo_2
6. filenametwo_1
7. filenametwo_2

Now i want to move (1,2,3)(4,5)(6,7) to each folder. Based on file name folder has to be created and respective files to be moved.
The following code works but file name it has in character range x:y but that will not works above file name examples.SO need some modification in file name pass.Thanks.

```
     import os, shutil
        os.chdir("<abs path to desktop>")
        for f in os.listdir("folder"):
            folderName = f[0:10]
            if not os.path.exists(folderName):
                os.mkdir(folderName)
                shutil.copy(os.path.join('folder', f), folderName)
            else:
                shutil.copy(os.path.join('folder', f), folderName)
```

Comment: What do you mean by *"character range x:y"*?

Comment: @Harith, Character Range--Filename :Refer 4th line in code f[0:10].

Comment: Is the length of the filename different in each case? In line 4 you initialize each folder name as first ten indices. But in your example you want to group first 3 separate then 4 and 5

Comment: @Fthomsan, as per My example only 3 folders to be created and folder 1 (1,2,3) folder 2(4,5) folder 3(6,7) files respectively. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Assumption being file will always end with "_number"

```
     import os, shutil
        os.chdir("<abs path to desktop>")
        for f in os.listdir("folder"):
            folderName = f[0:-2]
            if not os.path.exists(folderName):
                os.mkdir(folderName)
                shutil.copy(os.path.join('folder', f), folderName)
            else:
                shutil.copy(os.path.join('folder', f), folderName)
```

Comment: Thanks For your Reply. I don't seen the effect of _underscore. The code which i posted folderName = f[0:10] you modified folderName = f[0:-2]. I manged with the no of characters in the file name.Thank You.

Comment: f[x:y] with or without- sign takes characters. as per your assumption need _ character with count means folders to be created at first_ or as per given number.Thank You.

Comment: did this solution work for you? The assumption was that the foldername should all but the last 2 indices since that is how they are grouped in the question. E.I take off the last 2 characters from each filename and those are the folders that should be created. Happy to help/ modify if this is not what you needed

Comment: The solution is not worked because the one which I provided above is the same except the no of characters. I Really appreciate your kindness and help. Actually I need based on delimiter / special character recognize file move. Whether first underscore _ 1st or 2nd etc.  Thanks again for you your Response and Help.